# A Simple Slideshow with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, slide

I have been trying to make a Slide show with just JavaScript, but i have been falling on a problem if i set for the div's to change on click it works but when i set it on an Interval it just does not work.

```js
    var numSlide = 0, currentSlide=0;
var slides = new Array;

function slideShow(){
img = document.getElementsByClassName("slideDesign");
    for (i=0; i<img.length; i++){

        slides[numSlide]=img[i];

        if (numSlide == 0){
            img[i].style.zIndex ="4";
        }
        else{
            img[i].style.display = "0";
        }
    img[i].onclick = slideCheck;
        numSlide++;

    }
}

function slideCheck(){
    slides[currentSlide].style.zIndex="0";
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide >= numSlide){
       currentSlide = 0;
    }
     slides[currentSlide].style.zIndex= "4";
}


window.onload = slideShow;
```

```css
.slideDesign{
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
max-height:800px;
position: absolute;
top:0;
transition: z-index 1s;
}
 #div1{
    background-color:black;
    }
 #div2{
    background-color:red;
    }
  #div3{
    background-color:blue;
    }
 #div4{
    background-color:green;
    }
 #div5{
    background-color:cyan;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="slideShow">

<div id="div1" class="slideDesign"></div>
        <div id="div2" class="slideDesign"></div>
        <div id="div3" class="slideDesign"></div>
        <div id="div4" class="slideDesign"></div>
        <div id="div5" class="slideDesign"></div>


</div>    

</body>


</html>
```

On the Javascript just before the end of the slideShow function i can call the slideCheck function by clicking on the div and the div changes but if i change that line to window.setInterval("slideCheck();", 3000) i just does not work and i cannot figure out why.

Comment: Replace `window.onload = slideShow;` by `slideShow();window.setInterval(slideCheck, 3000);` (check my answer bellow)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first call you init function (slideShow) and after your slide change function (slideCheck) with interval.

```js
   var numSlide = 0, currentSlide=0;
var slides = new Array;

function slideShow(){
img = document.getElementsByClassName("slideDesign");
    for (i=0; i<img.length; i++){

        slides[numSlide]=img[i];

        if (numSlide == 0){
            img[i].style.zIndex ="4";
        }
        else{
            img[i].style.display = "0";
        }
    img[i].onclick = slideCheck;
        numSlide++;

    }
}

function slideCheck(){
    slides[currentSlide].style.zIndex="0";
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide >= numSlide){
       currentSlide = 0;
    }
     slides[currentSlide].style.zIndex= "4";
}
// Init your slide show
slideShow();
// Silde every 3 sec
window.setInterval(slideCheck, 3000);
```

```css
.slideDesign{
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
max-height:800px;
position: absolute;
top:0;
transition: z-index 1s;
}
 #div1{
    background-color:black;
    }
 #div2{
    background-color:red;
    }
  #div3{
    background-color:blue;
    }
 #div4{
    background-color:green;
    }
 #div5{
    background-color:cyan;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="slideShow">

<div id="div1" class="slideDesign"></div>
        <div id="div2" class="slideDesign"></div>
        <div id="div3" class="slideDesign"></div>
        <div id="div4" class="slideDesign"></div>
        <div id="div5" class="slideDesign"></div>


</div>    

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: you are the best... Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome. That will be nice if you can accept my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not really looking for custom building the Sliding functionality on your own, you can consider http://www.slidesjs.com/ 
Hope this helps.